# Segmentation fault while creating thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am getting segmentation fault while running this program. Using gdb, I have confirmed that it is at the `pthread_create` call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct point {
  int x;
  int y;
  char name;
};

void *start (void * P) {
  while (1) {

  }
}

main() {
  struct point P;
  P.name = 'P';
  P.x = 1;
  P.y = 2;

  pthread_t *tid;
  pthread_create (tid, NULL, (void *) start, (void *) &P);

  while (1) {

  }
}
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined a pointer `pthread_t *tid`, but never give it a valid value, change it to:

```
pthread_t tid;
pthread_create (&tid, NULL, (void *) start, (void *) &P);
```

Comment: Oh, yes! It works now. But, why does it work if instead of a struct pointer P, I pass an integer pointer?

Comment: @SagarJha Undefined behavior doesn't mean it can't work every time. It happened to work at times, but you can't rely on that.

Comment: Because you ignore P in start, its value is irrelevant and never used